# 23.04 - Weird spaces around some characters after uninstalling Deepin DE

Tags: gnome, fonts

I wanted to try Deepin DE on my Ubuntu 23.04 system, so I installed it, but I didn’t liked it. I removed all the packages it installed (I put the list in a file so I could remove them later).

However now there are (sometimes) weird spaces around some characters in Ubuntu font.

Examples : character ’ (U+2019, right single quotation mark), is displayed with a space (see screenshot, in Thunderbird). It's the same with the colon character used in hours (see screenshots too).

How can I get back to the regular font?

U+2019 in Thunderbird:

[image: Screenshot of U+2019 in Thunderbird]

Hour display in GNOME shell:

[image: Screenshot of hour display in Gnome-shell]

Hour display in Nautilus:

[image: Screenshot of hour display in Nautilus]

Comment: You could try a full reset of the gnome desktop to factory defaults - warning, you will have to customize what you changed again: `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`, and to take it one step further (full factory default dconf settings): `dconf reset -f /`